# ListView layout not updating after dynamic change

Tags: c#, maui

I am using .NET MAUI (.NET 7), and I am encountering an issue where the ListView, instead of pushing the other elements down, creates a scroll. Strangely, when I resize the software window, it updates the layout and pushes the elements down, removing the scroll. In the image below, you can see how it is currently working and how I would like it to work.

XML:

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="Organaizy.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Organaizy"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Organaizy.ViewModels">

    <Grid BackgroundColor="#282828" RowDefinitions="90*, 10*">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource CategoryLabelStyle}" Text="{Binding Name}">
                            <FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyout>
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Clicked="RenameCategory_Clicked" Text="Rename" />
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Clicked="DeleteCategory_Clicked" Text="Delete" />
                                </MenuFlyout>
                            </FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
                        </Label>

                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PDFs}" SelectionMode="None">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Label
                                                Padding="10"
                                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                TextColor="#FFF">
                                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2" Tapped="OpenPdf_Tapped" />
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ToggleDetails_Tapped" />
                                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
                                                    <MenuFlyout>
                                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Clicked="OpenPdf_Clicked" Text="Open" />
                                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Clicked="RenamePdf_Clicked" Text="Rename PDF" />
                                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Clicked="RenamePdfAuthor_Clicked" Text="Rename Author" />
                                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Clicked="ChangePdfCategory_Clicked" Text="Change Category" />
                                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Clicked="DeletePdf_Clicked" Text="Delete" />
                                                    </MenuFlyout>
                                                </FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
                                            </Label>

                                            <Grid
                                                ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto"
                                                IsVisible="False"
                                                RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto">
                                                <Label
                                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                                    Padding="10,5"
                                                    Opacity="0.9"
                                                    Text="{Binding Author, StringFormat='Author:  {0}'}"
                                                    TextColor="#FFF" />
                                                <Label
                                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                                    Padding="10,5"
                                                    Opacity="0.9"
                                                    Text="{Binding Pages, StringFormat='Pages:  {0}'}"
                                                    TextColor="#FFF" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="10,0"
            BackgroundColor="#FFF"
            Clicked="ShowAddOptions_Clicked"
            CornerRadius="20"
            FontSize="16"
            HeightRequest="40"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            Text="+"
            TextColor="#282828"
            WidthRequest="40" />
    </Grid>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Style x:Key="CategoryLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#FFF" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#282828" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#373737" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

</ContentPage>
```

ToggleDetails_Tapped Code:

```
    private void ToggleDetails_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var label = (Label)sender;
        var stacklayout = (StackLayout)label.Parent;
        var grid = (Grid)stacklayout.Children.First(c => c is Grid);

        grid.IsVisible = !grid.IsVisible;
    }
```

I have already tried switching from ListView to ScrollView/StackLayout with BindingLayout, but it didn't work as I wanted. This project is on my GitHub: DiegoAraujoDEVeloper/Organaizy
If you want to take a look.

[How it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDhG9.png)
[How it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO0mW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` (and the similar `CollectionView`) is designed for situations where there may not be enough vertical room.
It doesn't attempt to adjust the space it occupies.

- Instead, use `VerticalStackLayout` with a [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout#define-item-appearance) attached:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
  <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      ...
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I changed both the CollectionView and ListView to VerticalStackLayout with BindableLayout. Thank you very much.

Comment: I needed to add a ScrollView before the VerticalStackLayout because when there were many categories and PDFs, it wouldn't create a scroll.



<ScrollView>
            <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

Comment: I think it would also have worked if you kept the outer CollectionView, rather than replace that one with ScrollView and VerticalStackLayout. In some situations (hundreds of items), that is better for loading performance and memory, because CollectionView doesn't layout items until they are visible, whereas the StackLayouts create all their items when first loaded. If outer CollectionView doesn't fill screen's height, wrap it in `<Grid RowDefinitions="*">`